# Microsoft Excel write formula as a string of text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm wondering if in Microsoft Excel, it's possible to write a formula as a string of text. Whenever I write something such as `=sum(9+3)`, I want it to stay as `=sum(9+3)` and not complete it to `12`. In many of the programming languages I know, you can use symbols such as a backslash or a caret. I was wondering if there was something similar to this, as none of the keys I tried worked. I also don't want to use the built-in functions like `Show formula as text`.

Comment: Either `=SUM(9, 3)` or `=9+3` would be a better formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with ' or enter into cells with cell format as Text